# Cannot see UserControl VB.net (4.5)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, user-controls

I've created a Class Library project in the same project as my application. But I am not able to see that control in my application.

Please help,

Thank you,
Jaison

Comment: "Not able to see" is hopelessly vague.  Be explicit about what you expected to work and didn't.  If you don't see the control in the toolbox then you need to use Tools + Options to allow the toolbox to auto-populate.

Comment: To make it very clear, I will tell you exactly what I did. I tried adding the reference of my _UserControl_ **dll** to my application. It didn't work (reference has been added but, _UserControl_ was not populated in the tool box). Then I added the entire Class Library project to my application project and rebuild and reloaded everything. still no success. My tool box is set to load controls automatically. Is there anything else to be done? am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the reference to you class library?

Please take a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx
You can read about the different ways you can use other projects or dlls.

Hope this helps.
Pablo.

Comment: Yea, I added the reference too. But still it is not coming in my toolbox. Tool Box is set to load controls automatically. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1.] Tools >> Option >> Windows Forms Designer >> Automatically populate Toolbox = True. 
2.] restart Visual Studio.

[image]